# I need to create a python script which calls SOAP GET method using ZEEP or REQUEST modules

Tags: python, web-services, soap, python-3.5, oracle-fusion-apps

I am new to python. I need to fetch data from Oracle fusion cloud. I want to run a BI publisher report on Oracle fusion cloud instance using SOAP API call and get the data into CSV file.

I have tried with python ZEEP and REQUESTS modules but I am not getting expected results.

For example:
My WSDL: https://xxx.yy.us6.oraclecloud.com/xmlpserver/services/ExternalReportWSSService?wsdl

The operation I need to use is from above WSDL is 'runReport'

When I am running this request from SOAP UI for 'runReport' operation I am getting expected result like below:

[This screenshot is from SOAP UI where I am getting encoded data which is expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHPJ6.png)

I am using below code in python (Python 3.5) to call this API. I have used REQUESTS and ZEEP both:

**1.** **REQUESTS Module**:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from xml.etree import ElementTree


url="https://xxxx.yyyy.us6.oraclecloud.com/xmlpserver/services/ExternalReportWSSService?wsdl"
#headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
body = """<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:pub="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <pub:runReport>
         <pub:reportRequest>
            <pub:attributeFormat>csv</pub:attributeFormat>
            <!-- Flatten XML should always be false when we have XML type of output to display the XML tags as mentioned in BIP Data Model and display XML structure in as expected format -->
            <pub:flattenXML>false</pub:flattenXML>
            <pub:parameterNameValues>
                  <!--1st Parameter of BIP Report-->    
                  <pub:item>
                  <pub:name>p_name</pub:name>
                  <pub:values>
                      <pub:item>tapan</pub:item>
                  </pub:values>
                  </pub:item>
                  <!--2nd Parameter of BIP Report-->
                  <!--<pub:item>
                  <pub:name>p_to_date</pub:name>
                  <pub:values>
                      <pub:item>10-15-2019</pub:item>
                  </pub:values>
                  </pub:item>-->
            </pub:parameterNameValues>
            <pub:reportAbsolutePath>/Custom/Integration/test_data_rpt.xdo</pub:reportAbsolutePath>
            <!-- Setting sizeOfDataChunkDownload to -1 will return the output to the calling client -->
            <pub:sizeOfDataChunkDownload>-1</pub:sizeOfDataChunkDownload>
         </pub:reportRequest>
      </pub:runReport>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""

response = requests.get(url,data=body,headers=headers,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('XXXX', 'XXXX'))
print (response.text)
```

Above code is just giving me the list of operations available in the WSDL

**2.** **ZEEP Module**

```
from zeep import Client
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from zeep.transports import Transport

wsdl = "https://XXXX.XXXX.us6.oraclecloud.com/xmlpserver/services/ExternalReportWSSService?wsdl"
session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('XXXX', 'XXXX')

#An additional argument 'transport' is passed with the authentication details
client = Client(wsdl, transport=Transport(session=session))

request_payload= """<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:pub="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <pub:runReport>
         <pub:reportRequest>
            <pub:attributeFormat>csv</pub:attributeFormat>
            <!-- Flatten XML should always be false when we have XML type of output to display the XML tags as mentioned in BIP Data Model and display XML structure in as expected format -->
            <pub:flattenXML>false</pub:flattenXML>
            <pub:parameterNameValues>
                  <!--1st Parameter of BIP Report-->    
                  <pub:item>
                  <pub:name>p_name</pub:name>
                  <pub:values>
                      <pub:item>tapan</pub:item>
                  </pub:values>
                  </pub:item>
                  <!--2nd Parameter of BIP Report-->
                  <!--<pub:item>
                  <pub:name>p_to_date</pub:name>
                  <pub:values>
                      <pub:item>10-15-2019</pub:item>
                  </pub:values>
                  </pub:item>-->
            </pub:parameterNameValues>
            <pub:reportAbsolutePath>/Custom/Integration/test_data_rpt.xdo</pub:reportAbsolutePath>
            <!-- Setting sizeOfDataChunkDownload to -1 will return the output to the calling client -->
            <pub:sizeOfDataChunkDownload>-1</pub:sizeOfDataChunkDownload>
         </pub:reportRequest>
      </pub:runReport>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""

response = client.service.runReport(request_payload)
#Here 'request_data' is the request parameter dictionary.
#Assuming that the operation named 'runReport' is defined in the passed wsdl.
```

Above code is not working because I am not sure how to pass the request payload using ZEEP module.

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the requests module to dynamically schedule out reports from our Oracle Fusion cloud instance to UCM (slightly different than your request) but noticed the following differences in the content type distinction in the header and the method used for the response:

```
headers = {
    "content-type" : "application/soap+xml"
}

response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
```